# Optix sample without Cmake

Tags: compilation, nvidia, raytracing

i'm new in Optix world and i want to try to make new project in VS 2008.

My question: how can I use and modify the project "tutorial" without compiling all the examples included with SDK?

I try to create new project in VS2008 with "tutorial" files but don't work :/

Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am also new in optix and got the same problem.

I have compiled sample1 which give the green screen within Parallel Nsight 2.0 visual studio 2010.

You need to do the following if you are using nvidia parallel nsight:

1. change NVCC compilation type to PTX file in cuda c/c++ at project properties.
2. make sure you build optix-sdk samples files using cmake.
3. open optix-sample.sln and build the all projects.
4. new libraries has been created like sutil.lib which you need to link to your new project.
5. create a new cuda runtime project in my case i have used sample1 files.
6. make sure to do step 1 and then include optix header files and sutil.h from the optix-sdk.
7. link sutil.lib optix and opengl libraries like opengl32.lib and glut32.lib
8. You should now be able to build your project.
9. Finally you need optix sutil freeglut dll files to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

just open Optix-samples sol file , there you can see all the projects attached, find tutorial among them, right click on it and select "set as a startup project" .
Now you can run and edit tutorial alone.